# SpringBoot 2.1.9 -> 2.2.0 - health endpoint no longer works

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Trying to upgrade to Spring 2.2.0 and my `/health` endpoint no longer works, which causes problems with my AWS ALB health-checking.

Why does my health endpoint not work now?

Relevant `application.properties`:

```
# specifies that actuator endpoints be published on separate port
management.server.port=8081

# spring boot 2 moved this under "/actuator" but I don't like it, so this
management.endpoints.web.base-path=/

# This makes the /health endpoint return "status:UP" when the
# DB cannot be reached.
# Without this, overall status depends on datasource status.
#
# This is needed on the AWS side because ELB healthchecks used for ASG, so
# when DB became unreachable (because of RDS maintenance or other stuff-ups) or
# was just not reliably reachable (becaue of load testing resulting in
# connection pool exhaustion) - the ASG would start cycling instances
# unnecessarily.
management.health.defaults.enabled = false
```

Relevant Spring config:

```
public static String[] anonymousUrlPatterns(){
  return new String[] {
    // unauthenticated so the ELB can call it
    HEALTH_URL,
    // unauthenticated because that's what browsers do
    FAV_ICON_URL,
    ...
  }
}


private void configureEndpointRoles(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
  http.authorizeRequests().
    antMatchers(anonymousUrlPatterns()).permitAll().
    ...
    anyRequest().denyAll()
  ;
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
  this.configureSsl(http);

  this.configureEndpointRoles(http);

  http.csrf().disable();

  http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS);

  http.httpBasic().disable();

  http.cors();

  this.configureExceptionHandling(http);

  ...

}
```

This is the command that I use to check on a local machine:

```
curl -v http://localhost:8081/health
```

On 2.1.9, the curl returns `{"status":"UP"}` - on 2.2.0 I get no response.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was caused by `management.health.defaults.enabled = false`

The Spring folks have been fiddling with the actuator endpoints again and now the database status doesn't *display* as part of the health status any more.

At the same time, it seems they've re-purposed the setting to now mean "completely disable the health endpoint".

And for bonus points, though the DB status no longer *displays* as part of the `/health` endpoint, it's regressed to now fail and report `DOWN` if the DB is unreachable.

Comment: That looks like a regression to me. I've created https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/18841