# Make spring-boot 2.2.0 report status = UP, even when the DB is down?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Up to `spring-boot` `2.1.9`, I used to set `management.health.defaults.enabled = false` to decouple the `/health` endpoint overall status from the database status.

As of `2.2.0`, that specific setting no longer works that way (see: [SpringBoot 2.1.9 -> 2.2.0 - health endpoint no longer works](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58668560/924597)).

Is there a way to configure `spring-boot` to decouple the overall status of the `/health` endpoint from whether or not the datasource is up?

I'm inclined to just make my own endpoint hardcoded to return a status of 200.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand what you're trying to do and how disabling all defaults achieved what you've described.

What would be the point of having an endpoint that returns `200` unconditionally? That's seriously misleading IMO.

If you do not want the datasource health indicator, then you can disable that (and only that) using `management.health.db.enabled=false`.

If you want the datasource health check but want to be able to ignore it, create a group that exclude the `db` health check and use that for monitoring. See [the documentation for more details](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#health-groups)

Comment: "I don't really understand what you're trying to do" - see the link in the question.

Comment: I read it and I don't understand why disabling all defaults achieves what you've described. Sure it disables the datasource indicator but also all the other defaults.